# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel in table user

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I would like to call the column 'id_typeAdh' in the users table

```
Schema::create('type_adhs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_typeAdh');
            $table->string('libelle',120)->unique();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('tel_personnel');
            $table->string('tel_prof');
            $table->enum('societe',['x','y']);
            $table->enum('titre_civilite',['Mr','Mrs']);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('typeAdh_id');
            $table->foreign('typeAdh_id')->references('id_typeAdh')->on('type_adhs')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> ErrorMessage : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_typeadh_id_foreign` foreign key (`typeAdh_id`) references `type_adhs` (`id_typeAdh`) on delete cascade)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Laravel [the increments() method produces an unsigned integer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-increments).

But you added your typeAdh_id in the users table as a signed integer. You can't make that a foreign key to reference the unsigned primary key of the parent table.

So you should make it an unsigned integer to match:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('typeAdh_id');
$table->foreign('typeAdh_id')->references('id_typeAdh')->on('type_adhs')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$table->integer('typeAdh_id');` from users migration.

And use `$table->foreignId('typeAdh_id')->references('id_typeAdh')->on('type_adhs')->onDelete('cascade');`

just add 'Id' after 'foreign', so it's `foreignId`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your **typeAdh_id** unsigned inside your **users** table:

```
$table->integer('typeAdh_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('typeAdh_id')->references('id_typeAdh')->on('type_adhs')->onDelete('cascade');
```